# Flutter, how to pass a parameter to constructor

Tags: flutter

this is my code, i dont know how to pass this `listOfTiles` to my `StatefulWidget`, can u help me and describe how it works?

```
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new StuffInTilesState(listOfTiles[index]);//i want to pass this
          },
          itemCount: listOfTiles.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
 
class StuffInTiles extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  StuffInTilesState createState() => StuffInTilesState();//i know i need to change this, but i dont know how
}
 
class StuffInTilesState extends State<StuffInTiles> {
  final MyTile myTile;
  StuffInTilesState(this.myTile);//this is constructor, shuld this also be changed?
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  String name = "";
```

If u want to see my working code: https://pastebin.pl/view/c4dbc2af If u want to see my not working code: https://pastebin.pl/view/83f9cad0 (https://codeshare.io/GLLm66)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the widget class constructor and not the state class.
You can access the values ​​in the state class with *widget.YouProperty*

```
class StuffInTiles extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyTile myTile;

  const StuffInTiles(this.myTile);
  
  @override
  _StuffInTilesState createState() => _StuffInTilesState();
}

class _StuffInTilesState extends State<StuffInTiles> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: 
      Text(widget.myTile),);
  }
}
```